# Map hover in website using css and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to separate the province of Australia. I have following image:

[image]

For example, when I hover the mouse over Western Australia, it should only show "Western Australia".

Comment: This can be easy done by using MAP html tag - take a look here for reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of an image map and JavaScript to display info on hover.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function writeText(txt) {
    document.getElementById("desc").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src ="planets.gif" width ="145" height ="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" />

<map name="planetmap">
<area shape ="rect" coords ="0,0,82,126"
onmouseover="writeText('The Sun and the gas giant planets like Jupiter are by far the largest objects in our Solar System.')"
href ="sun.htm" target ="_blank" alt="Sun" title="Hover text here" />

<area shape ="circle" coords ="90,58,3"
onmouseover="writeText('The planet Mercury is very difficult to study from the Earth because it is always so close to the Sun.')"
href ="mercur.htm" target ="_blank" alt="Mercury" title="Hover text here"  />

<area shape ="circle" coords ="124,58,8"
onmouseover="writeText('Until the 1960s, Venus was often considered a twin sister to the Earth because Venus is the nearest planet to us, and because the two planets seem to share many characteristics.')"
href ="venus.htm" target ="_blank" alt="Venus" title="Hover text here"  />
</map> 

<p id="desc">Mouse over the sun and the planets and see the different descriptions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

See this example:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_imagemap

Comment: If you just want to show the name on hover, you can just use a title attribute on the area element and skip using JS altogether

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, answer updated to include example code, including the addition of a title attribute to show how that would be used if it was decided that a JS solution would be overkill

Comment: Can you tell me how at hover for this map area tags ?

Comment: What do you want to do on hover?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally create images of all of the different provinces & then either use the map tag or buttons along the bottom to display the specific province (with a white background) over the original map. The user would then only be able to see that specific province.